# Using the basics: GCF and LCD

Tags: java

So yeah, I'm going to rephrase everything what I said last time. I'm making a program for finding the GCF and LCD of two numbers. There are ways to find the GCF which is:

```
gcf = BigInteger.valueOf(x).gcd(BigInteger.valueOf(y)).intValue(‌​);
```

or Euclidean's Algorithm which has two types, the subtraction method and the remainder method.

We are NOT allowed to use ANY arrays or methods. We have to use control structures and repetitive structures.

I did the subtraction method but I find no luck there so I tried now the remainder method.

```js
int iA = 0, iB = 0, iG = 0, iL = 0, iR = 0;
if(iA != iB){
    if (iA > iB){
        iR = iA % iB;
        iG = iB / iR;
        iL = (iA*iB)/iG;
    }
    else{
        iR = iB % iA;
        iG = iA / iR;
        iL = (iA*iB)/iG;
    }
    System.out.println("The GCF is: " + iG);
    System.out.println("The LCD is: " + iL);
}
else{
    System.out.println("The GCF is: " + iA);
    System.out.println("The LCD is: " + iA);
```

Now the remainder method suggests that if remainder == 0, then the last remainder value is the GCF of two numbers. I'm expecting to execute a `while` or `do-while` structure but I can't think of a way. My code up there now inputs in a wrong way.

e.g.

```js
First Number: 120
Second Number: 50
The GCF is: 2
```

But the gcf of (120,50) should be 10. If solved it goes like:

```
iR = 120 % 50
iG = 50 / 20
```

Anyway, LCD can be gained if the product of the two numbers is divided by the GCF so it's kind of a hectic if I don't find the GCF.

Any help of would be a much appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Definitely, here's the answer using the Remainder Method.

```js
int iA = 0, iB = 0, iL = 0, iR;
System.out.print("Enter First Number: ");
iA = var.nextInt();
System.out.print("Enter Second Number: ");
iB = var.nextInt();
iL = (iA*iB);
if(iA != iB){
    if (iA > iB){
        do{
            iR = iA % iB;
            iA = iB;
            iB = iR;
        }while(iR != 0);
    iL /= iA;
    System.out.println("The GCF is: " + iA);
    }
    else if (iB > iA){
        do{
            iR = iB % iA;
            iB = iA;
            iA = iR;
        }while(iR != 0);
    iL /= iB;
    System.out.println("The GCF is: " + iB);
    }   
    System.out.println("The LCD is: " + iL);
}
else{
    System.out.println("The GCF is: " + iA);
    System.out.println("The LCD is: " + iA);
}
```